# passing reference to this from chrome socket call

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

In my Chrome App I need somehow Chrome to give the the reference to my object 'identity_service' in **this** variable when the callback is executed, but I don't know how.

This is my constructor:

```
function Identity(identity_host,identity_port) {

    this.identity_host=identity_host;
    this.identity_port=identity_port;
    this.socket_fd=0;

    chrome.sockets.tcp.create({}, this.socket_create_callback);

}
```

The function socket_create_callback is defined like this:

```
Identity.prototype.socket_create_callback=function(info) {
    console.log('info='+info);
    console.log('constructor name:'+this.constructor.name);
    console.log('hostname='+this.identity_host);
    this.socket_fd=info.socketId;
}
```

This is how I create it:

```
var identity_service=new Identity("localhost",4433);
```

Without object oriented programming Chrome calls the callback function with the parameter 'info' and it works fine. But when using OOP the '**this**' variable doesn't hold the reference to my 'Identity' object otherwise the 'hostname' would not be undefined. This is what I get in the console log:

```
identity.js:21 info=[object Object]
identity.js:22 constructor name:Object
identity.js:23 hostname=undefined
```

With correct invocation of the callback the name of the csontructor would be 'Identity'. How can this be fixed?

The Chrome API call for creating a socket is this:

**create**

```
chrome.sockets.tcp.create( SocketProperties properties, function callback)
```

Creates a TCP socket.

Comment: Well, of course. You should bind the actual object: `chrome.sockets.tcp.create({}, this.socket_create_callback.bind(this));`. There's no way the other function would know which `this` to use.

Comment: A detailed answer: [How to access the correct \`this\` / context inside a callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20279485)

Comment: There are hundreds of duplicates of this type of question here.

Comment: @wOxxOm but how do you pass the  "info" parameter which Chrome should return ?

Comment: Maybe that answer I've linked is not the best, but you can (and should) read in the documentation for `bind`: in short, when it is used with only one parameter it redefines only `this`, all conventional parameters will be passed as is. There are other methods (faster) than `bind`, see that answer for examples or find a better one, there are lots.